# If-Else loop vs. Ifelse(); how are they different and how to give the same result

Tags: r

I wanted to write a if-loop, possibly that gives the same result from:
`K = ifelse(arg1 < arg2,1,2)`, which results:
`K = {1,2,1,1,2,2,1,...}`

I was trying to do this:

```
if (arg1 < arg2) {
    K = 1;
  if (arg1 > arg2) {
    K = 2;
  }
  }
```

But this gives me an error that `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedthe condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.`

I was actually hoping to use if-else, but I am having hard time implementing it.

Comment: Why not use `ifelse()`? It is vectorized and seems to be optimal here. Just an exercise?

Comment: I am trying to practice if-else as well to work like ifelse().

Comment: Why do you need a loop? What is wrong with a vector version using implicit conversion from logical to numeric  `(arg1 < arg2) + 1L`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that warning because `length(arg1)` is  greater than 1 and `if` can handle only one value at a given time so even if you pass it the entire `arg1` it is going to by default take only first value of i.e `arg1[1]`.

Something like this should work

```
arg1 <- 10:1
arg2 <- 5:14
K <- numeric(length = length(arg1))

for (i in seq_along(arg1)) {
   if (arg1[i] < arg2[i])
      K[i] = 1
   else
      K[i] = 2
}

K
#[1] 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

which also gives same output with `ifelse`

```
ifelse(arg1 < arg2, 1, 2)
#[1] 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Make sure that `length` of `arg1` is same as that of `arg2`.

Comment: what's the difference between `1:length(arg1)` to `seq_along(arg1)`?

Comment: @colbyjackson You'll not find any difference in most of the cases but it is safer way to write code. If you get an empty `arg1` for any reason, let's say `arg1 <- numeric()`. Now check the output of `1:length(arg1)` and `seq_along(arg1)`. In the former case it will execute the loop 2 times (1, 0) and in later case, it will not go into the `for` loop at all since `arg1` is empty.